# Nginx allow post requests from a certain server

Tags: nginx

I have a service being accessed through nginx and I wish to white list post requests only. I have written this in my nginx config file:

```
location / {
  if ( $request_method ~ ^(POST|PUT)$ ) {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
  }
  if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|PUT|HEAD)$ ) {
    return 405;
  }
}
```

This config gives me the following error -

```
nginx: [emerg] "allow" directive is not allowed here
```

On the other hand, if I write the allow directive out of the `if` block like this, it works.

```
location / {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|PUT|HEAD)$ ) {
    return 405;
  }
}
```

I believe this means that I can't use the `allow` directive in an `if` block. Am I doing something wrong here? If not, is there a workaround for achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http {
  geo $allowed_post_put {
    default 0;
    127.0.0.1 1;
    ::1 1;
  }
  map $request_method:$allowed_post_put $return_405 {
    "POST:0" 1; 
    "PUT:0" 1;
  }
}

location / {
  if ( $return_405 = 1 ) {
    return 405;
  }
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html - geo module allows to create variables depending on client IP address.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html - map module creates variables whose values depend on values of other variables.

`if` directive from rewrite module does not allow complex logical expressions, just single variable comparsion. So we use map module to create variable that depends both on  client IP and request method.

**UPD**: An alike configuration with geo/map/if hack works fine for me in production.

Comment: I don't seem to understand the code, can you please explain how it works?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @KeshavAgarwal Does it work for you?

Comment: Hi, I added the geo and map blocks in the nginx.conf file. No matter what variable name I choose for `return_405`, it always raises `invalid variable name "return_405"`. I've tried to change the variable's name to all alphabets  like `foo` and ones without special characters like `return405`, but none of them seems to work. Can you tell me where the problem lies?

Comment: My mistake, all variables in `map` directive should have `$` prefix. I fixed the answer

Comment: It's giving 405 error on post/put when trying to access `localhost:8000` and `127.0.0.1:8000` using postman.

Comment: @KeshavAgarwal I just checked out this configuration, works for me. Also I have a lot alike configuration with geo/map hack working in production. Change `return 405` to something else, like `return 418`, and you will see if 405 is returned by nginx or by underlying code.

Comment: Another if block after this one was the culprit for this, I changed that and now it's working fine. Thanks a lot! :D