# Allowing POST requests from a single IP address only on NGINX

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration

Is it possible to allow only a single IP address to make POST requests and deny everyone else on the same grounds on NGINX?

[Seen an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/835602/nginx-allow-post-requests-from-a-certain-server/835607) related to this one but the solution offered there needs the rule to be applied server-wide. I need to do this on a virtual host level, without affecting the other sites hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your virtual host directory , create an .htaccess file.

You can use rules like this for deny all post requests:

```
# deny all POST requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then allow the whitelist:

```
# whitelist POST requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/contact.php [NC]
     RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1 
     RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
 </IfModule>
```

More information on [this site](https://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/)

EDIT : for NGINX you can traslate precedent rule with [this online tool](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/), for instance:

```
if ($request_method ~ "POST"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    return 403;
    break;
}


if ($request_method ~ "POST"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($remote_addr !~ "127.0.0.1"){
    set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "321"){
   return 403;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Question is specifically asking for Nginx, not Apache.

Comment: pardon, i'll edit the post with converted info for ngnix

Comment: OK, I have modified yours a bit and it seems like working! Thanks a lot @DanieleLicitra :)
`if ($request_method ~ "POST"){
 set $poster P$poster;
}
if ($remote_addr !~ "111.222.333.444"){
 set $poster B$poster;
}
if ($poster = "BP"){
 return 444;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The answer you need is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/760359/nginx-allow-deny-based-on-ip-user-agent-combination/760370).

You would additional need a check for post, which would be `($request_method = POST )`.

So the block would look something like the following (which I have not been able to test):

```
location @location {
  if ($request_method = POST) {
     allow IP;
     deny all;
  }
}
```

Docs for the access module are [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html).